# Android change button background image with java?

Tags: android

I'm attempting to have a button that mutes sound in app which now works. My new problem is that i want the image to change within my IF statement.

Button code from layout:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/mute"
            android:background="@drawable/sound"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"


     />
```

Here is my code for IF/mute sound code:

```
                           if (cmute == false){

                    Editor editor = getPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("mute", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    Editor editor2 = getPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("notice", true);
                    editor.commit();                  
                }
                if (cmute == true){
                    Editor editor = getPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("mute", false);
                    editor.commit();
                    Editor editor2 = getPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("notice", false);
                    editor.commit();
                                    }
```

I need to add code to each IF, one to display sound on (soundon.png)button background and one to display the sound off (soundoff.png) background button image. (button ID id'mute')

Many Thanks. =]

Comment: Just change the image of the button that you pressed. Wherever that image is.

Comment: Well, where is the actual button you press? Like can you show the `Button`. Cuz I don't see it in your example code above.

Comment: button code from layout updated, thank u.. i previously tried to simply add that line with diff image but no go my way.. =?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *setBackgroundResource* to change the background.

---

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.mute);
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.soundoff);
```

Comment: Well you beat me to it -_- but yes. @Droidster just use this as a starting point to correctly change the image whenever that button is pressed. Except make sure you do `Button btn = this.findViewById(R.id.mute)` because the way he did it would require you to make `btn` a global variable from `onCreate`, which is fine as well. But keep that in mind. I am assuming you have the image change code in a separate class. So thats why I say this.

Comment: Thank you both Andy & SquiresSquire!